# Can I use a command (such as "tree") without installing it system wide?

Tags: linux, command-line, ssh, administrator

I'm connected to a Linux box through SSH on which I don't have administrative privileges. The command I wish to use is called [`tree`](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/tree.htm), but it isn't installed.

Is there any way I can load the `tree` program into my home directory and run it without the need to install it system wide?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`tree` doesn't seem to have particular dependencies (libc6) so I guess you can simply copy the executable (located in `which tree` on another system with `tree` installed or alternatively you can compile it from source, [here](http://mama.indstate.edu/users/ice/tree/)'s the home page of the project) in a directory on the Linux box which you're connected, say `~/bin/`, then you just need to update your `$PATH` environment variable to add that directory.

If you're using `Bash` put this in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
PATH=$PATH:~/bin/
```

**Note:** Be sure to match architecture and OS.

Comment: I can tell it's running linux by calling "echo $(uname)", but how do I figure out the architecture?

Comment: Show me the output of `uname -m`.

Comment: That gives you the machine hardware name (e.g. `x86_64`, `i686`, ...).

Comment: @Corey: `echo` is unnecessary. `uname` (and most others) do their own output.

Answer (score 5):

```
cd $HOME
# download latest tree source to home directory
wget http://mama.indstate.edu/users/ice/tree/src/tree-1.7.0.tgz
# unpack
tar xzfv tree-1.7.0.tgz
cd tree-1.7.0/
make
# install to $HOME directory
make install prefix=$HOME/bin
# this will create folders bin, and man
cd $HOME
# remove original source folder
rm -rf tree-1.7.0

# run tree
$HOME/bin/tree
# view man page
$HOME/man tree
```

Comment: Isnt't there an excedent /bin in the prefix ? 
 The executable I get is `/home/[myUsername]/bin/bin/tree`.  Bah, the essential part is that it works with a simple copy/paste

Answer (score 3):

You would usually build and install it on the prefix `$HOME`. That means the binary would go into `$HOME/bin`, libraries into `$HOME/lib` and so on. Then you insure that these directories appear on `$PATH`, `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `$MAN_PATH`, etc (usualy by editting your shell startup files) and it will work transparently.

Here's a recipe that will work with many programs

```
$ cd $HOME
$ mkdir src
$ cd src
$ wget http://host.name/path/to/program.tgz
$ tar xzfv program.tgz
$ cd program
$ ./configure --PREFIX=$HOME
$ make
$ make install
```

Note that unlike installing on `/usr/local` there is never any need for root privilege.

Comment: I suggest putting stuff in $HOME/local/ to keep the root folder a bit tidier.

Comment: @mankoff: I never thought of that. I've simple stopped seeing those directories.